# What's the cause of this small, round, brown stain on a drywall ceiling?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, ceiling, extension

My kitchen extension is 3 years old. It is a timber frame drywall extension with plasterboard wall. This 1cm round circle has just appeared about 12 feet above and two feet away from my cooker and extractor. Am I looking at a roof leak and or possibly a rusted drywall pop? The area is dry to touch, no water observed leaking downwards. No other areas of stain on the roof. Please advise me .

[image]

Comment: That's not a drywall pop, and if it was a rusted screw it would still indicate a leak. Either something splattered from below or leaked from above. That's about all I can say with no other knowledge of the situation.

Comment: 12 feet above seems like it would take some work to be from the cooker/cook.  It is small so finding a tiny roof leak will be hard, unless lucky enough to be up there to see the drip.  Water will travel some from coming though the roof to landing on the ceiling, in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Its not from a nail.  It is water dripping in the centre of the circle and spreading outwards.

- I would put a small bowl above it.  Support it by putting some decking timber or similar between trusses.  And see if it collects water over the next rain.
- If there is none (the likelihood is high that there will be none), then you need to track it.
- If there is space then get up there after it has been raining for 5 or 10 minutes
- Feel around on pipes, cables, timber etc to see if it is tracking.
- If no luck, then you need to get on the roof and inspect all flashings, overlaps etc.

Comment: I wouldn't use a bowl.  I'd lay a sheet of paper towel, or toilet paper—much easier to see if it gets wet, and no need to get up there before the water evaporates in the bowl.

Comment: Additionally, paper towel/TP can be spread across a wide area to catch the drips from wherever they may be coming, making for a faster discovery process. Just look for the wrinkled/water damaged paper.